# Идентификация устройства (пользователя) на Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, vpn, outline

Я делаю VPN-сервис на основе Outline и хочу сделать так, чтобы по одной ссылке подключалось только одно устройство, а другие не могли. Ссылки я собираюсь сделать динамичными, то есть доступ к VPN будет через json файлы лежащие на основном сервере, где и будет API на Django. У пользователя будет примерно такая ссылка: `ssconf://<адрес_основного_сервера>/user61589371.json` Эту ссылку пользователь получит через телеграм бота. Проблема в том, что я хочу как-то ограничить количество устройств, а именно хочу сделать систему "1 ссылка на 1 устройство" и я не знаю как идентифицировать устройства. Как я читал в интернете, айпи может быть изменчив.

Comment: Вы предполагаете использование ссылок как некоего механизма подтверждения оплаты и постоянного доступа или что-то, что даст возможность разово подключиться к VPN?

Comment: @Стас Подтверждение оплаты не связано с этой проблемой, мне надо чтобы один пользователь не делился ни с кем своей ссылкой, а пользовался сам и только с одного устройства

Comment: Можно пойти через fingerprintjs. Встроить на страницу юзера скрипт, который отправит на API фингерпринт, бэкенд его сохранит, а юзеру передастся файл ответом от сервера. При последущих запросах к API, бэкенд должен проверить, есть ли уже такой fingerprint при запросе -> такого то файла. Если нет, то реджектить пользователя.

Comment: Соответственно юзер должен запрашивать не /user61589371.json . А например просто /61589371 . Предварительно отдайте страницу с скриптом получения отпечатка, которая постучится в ваше API после прогрузки, и отдастся либо файл либо реджект

Comment: Храните в базе идентификаторы, и связывайте их с отпечатками клиентскими. Передавать их можно в каком нибудь кастомном хедере

Comment: https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs

Comment: @exord Мне это ни к чему. Пользователь подключается к VPN через приложение outline

Comment: Причем тут VPN и ограничение доступа к сервису? Они несвязны должны быть друг с другом

Comment: хотите что бы пользователь "не делился ни с кем своей ссылкой, а пользовался сам и только с одного устройства" Так резолвите это на стороне сервиса

Comment: @exord Для подключения к VPN бот пользователю дает ссылку (естественно после оплаты подписки), и этот пользователь сейчас может подключить через эту ссылку сколько угодно своих устройств к VPN, а мне этого не надо. У меня кроме VPN серверов есть основной сервер, где будет лежать бэкенд на Django и код самого бота для телеграма. Через этот основной сервер будет осуществляться получение доступа к VPN серверам, в json файлах будет такая информация как адрес VPN сервера, пароль и способ хеширования пароля.

Comment: Понимаете, что не утекла ссылка. Вам нужно как то идентифицировать клиента - по какому либо параметру(клиентскому.)(он не должен меняться при перезапросах) При запросе файла, он должен вам его передать. Вы его сохраняете и и далее при любых повторных запросах на эту ссылку, вы должны сверять пришедший параметр от клиента с тем что был передан ранее - при первом запросе.

Comment: Либо клиент должен сам генерировать подпись(не обязательно фингерпринт) и сохранять её у себя. И далее каждый раз её отправлять при запросах файла

Comment: Если VPN обогащает как то запросы, это тоже можно использовать. Типо Client такой то. Исследуйте, что вам в хедерах приходит. Меняется ли это от подключения клиента к подключению и тд.

Comment: @exord хорошо, попробую сделать что-то